# How to tell what's consuming a storage container queue in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, message-queue

So this is a bit of a weird one, I have a cloud setup with a queue 'my-queue', and a function app that consumes that queue.  If the function app encounters an error, it puts the message in a secondary queue called 'my-queue-poison'.

I was getting weird behavior where it looked like messages were disappearing from the queue and never triggering the logging that I'd expect in the function app (as in I have a log call the second the handler starts).

I've done a lot to simplify the situation, and it does appear as though something is occasionally taking those message, and putting them in the poison queue.

I've had a good look for whatever is eating those messages, but my company has a lot of function apps and it's a bit impractical to investigate every one, but I think maybe one from a different environment is misconfigured.

Is there any way in Azure to see what's subscribed to a queue?

Comment: Have you integrated application insigths in your applications? If so you can query the dependencies based on the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

> I was getting weird behavior where it looked like messages were disappearing from the queue

Yes, messages will disappear from queue when it is successfully processed or when there is some error with storage account or our code to send messages,and I faced similar issue of disappearing.
Even if the message disappears you will get to know about logs using below kql query:

```
AzureActivity 
|where OperationName contains "Write queue" and ActivityStatus contains "Succeeded"
```

[image]

I do agree with @Peter Bons that you should integrate application insights and then export logs of your applications and query the dependencies based on your storage account.

I created a new storage account and new queue for it and disappearing of messages is gone.

After creating new storage account, the messages in queue are not disappearing:

[image]

Alternatively, you should check your function application logs and then decide which is using the function app.

[image]

If the issue still persists , I would suggest you to raise  a support request.